# finding latest entry in DB and all other before it in a different table

Tags: php, function, timestamp

This is a fairly easy thing in theory but i havent got a clue how to do it. What i need is a method to find the latest timestamp/entry in a table called 'answers' in an MySQL DB. And upon finding this, to find all IP's stored in a table called 'ip' by timestamp that occur before the said mention 'answers' entry.

Any ideas? Im guessing an if() function would be the best way?

Edit: table structure where 'ip' exists.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `votes` (
`id` int(250) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ip` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`answer_id` int(250) NOT NULL,
`poll_id` int(250) NOT NULL,
`timestamp` int(250) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

And the table where the 'answers' live

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `answers` (
`id` int(250) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`poll_id` int(250) NOT NULL,
`answer` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

Comment: Could you provide the relevant db schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely this can be a pure database solution an doesn't need anything doing in PHP?

Assuming the tables are in the same database, both have a `timestamp` column and are named `answers` and `votes` respectively, then:

```
SELECT * FROM votes v
WHERE v.timestamp <= (SELECT max(a.timestamp) FROM answers a)
```

**EDIT :** Replaced names according to your schema, but I don't see a `timestamp` column in `answers`?

Comment: i suppose so, i'll try this out. I need to allow all ip addresses stored previous to the new answer to be ignored just once.

Comment: yea maybe find the highest 'id' instead, i never realised my mistake

Comment: @Ricki OK, I'll leave my answer as it is and let you adapt it to your exact column names then

Comment: had a chance to try it out, rewrote my database tables, works just fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from ip x where x.timestamp <= (select max(y.timestamp) from answer y)
```

Comment: it takes just one row from y (answer) the max row
then it compares all the ip timestamps against this ...

Answer (score 0):

To get the latest timestamp you can use...

```
SELECT timestamp_field FROM answers ORDER BY timestamp_field DESC LIMIT 1
```

Then run a second query matching the result from that query.