# using php to find highest number of votes in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

im looking for a way in php to grab entries from a table named 'answers' in a mysql database, then grab entries from a table called 'votes' and calculate from them, the answer with the highest vote. I cant seem to find any help on this.

The structures can be viewed [here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/7741582/finding-latest-entry-in-db-and-all-other-before-it-in-a-different-table)

How it works is the users vote gets stored in the 'votes' table and is recognized by the 'answer_id' column, i just dont no how count them all and determine the answer with the highest votes

Comment: `JOIN` the 2 tables, then `GROUP BY answer.id` and `SELECT COUNT(*)`

Comment: when you say 'GROUP BY answer.id' do you mean 'answer_id'?

Comment: No, I meant `answers.id` (if you do an `answers LEFT JOIN vites`). If you do an `INNER JOIN`, any of the two is equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about

```
SELECT a.*, COUNT(v.id) tot
FROM answers a INNER JOIN votes v
on a.id = v.answer_id
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY tot DESC
```

If you want to get also answers without any vote, use:

```
SELECT a.*, COUNT(v.id) tot
FROM answers a LEFT JOIN votes v
on a.id = v.answer_id
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY tot DESC
```

Comment: wow, fast response, i often wonder what my questions would be like if i had studied harder. This is great. Many thanks

Comment: And use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` to show also answers without any votes.

Comment: @ypercube: thanks for your correct suggestion. I edited my post adding new query. Thanks!!